# Why is CalendarProvider not getting all events?

Tags: android, android-calendar

I'm creating an app that will create a specific calendar and manage events inside it.

For now, for testing purpose, I want to show every events I have in my provider, and I'm doing it with this code :

```
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(
    CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI,
    new String[]{CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART},
    null, null, 
    CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART
);
```

Here, I get an unexpected behaviour : the earliest event I get here happened the 08/16/2015, even if my google agenda show me events of 2014.
The only exception of these are recurring events which occur in that last year (8 of them versus 632 total)

Why would the contentProvider trim my calendar at 1 year like this ? How to prevent this or synchronize this specific Calendar better ?

Is this behaviour documented somewhere ?